# Did Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi learn the Angel of Death's personal name?

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, names, rabbis, satan

I recently heard that when Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi was in Paradise he learned the personal name of the Angel of Death/Satan. Can anyone provide a source for this claim?

In [Ketubot 77b](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.77b.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) it is written:

> "When Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi was on the verge of dying, they said to the Angel of Death: Go and perform his bidding, as he is a righteous man and deserves to die in the manner he sees fit. The Angel of Death went and appeared to him. Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi said to him: Show me my place in paradise. He said to him: Very well. Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi said to him: Give me your knife that you use to kill mortals, lest you frighten me on the way. He gave it to him. When he arrived there, in paradise, he lifted Rabbi Yehoshua so he could see his place, and he showed it to him. Rabbi Yehoshua jumped and fell into that other side, thereby escaping into paradise.
>
> The Angel of Death grabbed him by the corner of his cloak. Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi said to him: I swear that I will not come with you. The Holy One, blessed be He, said: If he ever in his life requested dissolution concerning an oath he had taken, he must return to this world with the Angel of Death, as he can have his oath dissolved this time also. If he did not ever request dissolution of an oath, he need not return. Since Rabbi Yehoshua had in fact never requested dissolution of an oath, he was allowed to stay in paradise. The Angel of Death said to him: At least give me my knife back. However, he did not give it to him, as he did not want any more people to die. A Divine Voice emerged and said to him: Give it to him, as it is necessary to kill the created beings; death is the way of the world. Eliyahu the Prophet announced before him: Make way for the son of Levi, make way for the son of Levi."

Now as I heard, when Rabbi Yehoshua held the Angel of Death's knife, he carved his name into his arm. The name was said to be "T-r....o-k-e". Upon returning the knife, it is said that it faded and he immediately forgot it.

If anyone knows where this information is from, I would be greatly appreciative to find out. I have never heard of this name, and have only ever known the Angel of Death/Satan by his name "S-a....m-a-e-l". Perhaps I'm just ignorant of the source, but I'd rather not accept such claims without knowing where they came from.

Many thanks in advance!

(Edit: I refined the question and slightly edited some names, in case I caused any offense or misdeed by them. The names are only written for the sake of discussion, despite their darker nature.)

Comment: An upvote to cancel out the downvote. I wonder whether at least the part about "carving it into his arm" might be a misremembering or misconstrual (by your source) of [Kol Bo](https://www.sefaria.org/Kol_Bo.120.2?vhe=Kol_Bo_1547_Venice_Unknown_Publisher&lang=he)'s recounting of the story, in which the angels complain to G-d, ראה מה עשה בן לוי בזרוע. But בזרוע there is a metaphorical term, "by force," not the literal "with his arm."

Comment: Ahhh I see, that's pretty interesting to know. First of all thank you too. The version of the story I was told was given to me by word of mouth only. So I'm unaware of some details I'll admit, or perhaps they aren't entirely accurate. Still fascinating nonetheless.

Comment: This sounds like some strange, distorted variation of the text from Sefer Toldot Yeshua HaNotzri.

Comment: Open up a shoreshei hashemos and you'll find out for yourself

Comment: I heard in the name of the Brisker Rav that - https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94:%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%9C%D7%91_%D7%9C -  וַיֹּאמֶר לָמָּה זֶּה תִּשְׁאַל לִשְׁמִי - is the name of the yetzer hara / samael / malach ha'maves. The name is - Why do you ask my name? Ie. this malach is nameless.