# Is R. Yehoshua ben Levi ever identified with a particular angel?

Tags: death, malach-angel, eliyahu-hanavi, gan-eden, melchizedek

Related to this question:
[Did Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi learn the Angel of Death's personal name?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/116987/did-rabbi-yehoshua-ben-levi-learn-the-angel-of-deaths-personal-name)

We learn that Rabbi Yehoshua ben Levi entered the Garden of Eden alive without dying.

This is equated in the The Terumas HaDeshen and Minchas Chinuch to Elijah's entry to heaven as essentially being transformed into an angel.
Similarly, Enoch tells us that Melchizedek was taken by the archangel Gabriel (Michael in some manuscripts) to the Garden of Eden and was thus preserved from the Deluge without having to be in Noah's Ark.
Additionally, we hear of Enoch himself transforming in the same way.

Enoch is shown to become Metatron.
Elijah is sometimes (in early tradition) identified with the angel Sandalphon.
Similarly, the Qumran Scrolls indicate that Melchizedek was used as a name of the Archangel Michael (when he is not rescued by Michael, presumably).

Does anyone know of any writings elaborating on Yehoshua being identified with any particular angel after he entered Paradise alive?

Comment: He swore to remain in Gan Eden and not return (בשבועתא דלא אתינא).. a restriction that may impede any kind of angelic duties?